# Transfer database using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

The production server that hosts my rails app is being wiped and started again, as a result i will need to transfer my rails app onto the new system. The source isnt a problem i can just pull down from git again but the database is another matter. I could install phpmyadmin or something similar to access the database but i was wondering if there was something in rails (possibly a rake task) that would let me dump the current database and then import it onto a new server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need Rails or PHPMyAdmin for this. Assuming you're using MySQL, simply ssh to your server:

```
mysqldump -u root -p databasename > database.sql
```

Then on the other system:

```
mysql -u root -p newdatabasename < database.sql
```

Easy, huh?

Comment: "mysql -h remote.server.example.com -u username -psecret databasename"

if you want to seed a remote server

Comment: Does this copy the data or just the tables?

Answer (score 5):

If it is a recurring task, you could also put that into a rake task under lib/tasks:

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Dump database"
  task :dump => :environment do
    exec "mysqldump -u root -p databasename > database.sql"
  end
  desc "Restore database"
  task :restore => :environment do
    exec "mysql -u root -p newdatabasename < database.sql"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, if the manual commands work I will probabbly stick this so that the db can be backed up with the app (once i get the backups on the production server working again)